# qooxdoo: Binding more than one proberty to a label

Tags: qooxdoo

Is it possible to bind more than one proberty to a label?

I have qx-Object with the proberties "value" and "unit" and I would like to bind both proberties to a label. If I do it like this 
`this.bind("tag.value", label, "value");
this.bind("tag.unit", label, "value");`
than only the unit gets displayed in the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this is possible using a converter in both bindings which reads the other value:

```
var tag = qx.data.marshal.Json.createModel({value: 12, unit: "px"});
var l = new qx.ui.basic.Label();
this.getRoot().add(l);

tag.bind("value", l, "value", {converter : function(data, source) {
  return data + tag.getUnit();
}});

tag.bind("unit", l, "value", {converter : function(data, source) {
  return tag.getValue() + data;
}});
```